# Insert on ObservableCollection causes Win32Exception

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

I'd like to `Insert` an item into an `ObservableCollection` which is bound using a `ComboBox` on the dispatcher thread (ensured by using a `DispatcherTimer`). The insert call will cause the application to crash with a non-debuggable `Win32Exception` (looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RthXZ.png)), if an item is selected in the `ComboBox`. When the item is `Add`ed instead of `Insert`ed, the code will run as expected.

Minimal code example:

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="77,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">

        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ComboBox>

    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="202,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button_Click"/>

</Grid>

</Page>
```

And the code behind:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyData> Data { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        DataContext = this;

        Data = new ObservableCollection<MyData>()
        {
            new MyData { Text = "Lorem" }
        };

        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += (_, __) => { Data.Insert(0, new MyData { Text = "Ipsum" }); /* crash */ };
        timer.Start();
    }

}
```

Is there a way to insert the item without causing the app to crash?

Comment: THe problem seems to occur once you try to 'touch' selected item - insert uses Array.Copy, so the selected item is copied and then replaced at old index with new item, this probably is not handeled by Combobox. Note that when you select item at 0 position and then insert items at 1st index, there will be no exception.

Comment: Preserving the selected item and setting it to `null` before insert seems to work (which is kind of hacky as I need to handle this case in the data-bound property implementation). Feel free to add an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to occur once you try to 'touch' selected item - *ObservableCollection* uses *List.Insert* method, which as you can see at [reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) uses *Array.Copy*. The selected item is copied and then replaced at old index with new item, this probably is not handeled by *Combobox* and causes exception.

Note that when you select item at 0 position and then insert items at 1st index, there will be no exception. Similar - if no item is selected, there will be no exception while inserting at any position. So as a workaround, if appliciable, you may try to set *Combobox.Selected* item to *null* before starting inserting, what may work.